# PDO connection refused with laravel, but not with $con = new PDO()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I've configured mysql for my laravel 5.0-dev project like so:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST') ?: 'localhost',
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE') ?: 'homestead',
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME') ?: 'homestead',
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD') ?: 'secret',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

However, I get connection refused ('PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]') whenever I try to interact with the database using either php artisan, or the laravel app itself.

The weird thing is, when I run the code below, the connection doesn't get refused.

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=homestead;host=localhost';
$user = 'homestead';
$password = 'secret';

try
{
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I've been googling for 3 hours now and I haven't found a single solution which actually works. So any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the environment variables set with different values? Debug the `env()` calls first, then try configuring laravel without the `env()` calls at all (using the static strings localhost,homestead only).

Comment: And wait a minute - unless `env()` is defined by Laravel (I don't know, is it?)  PHP's function for retrieving environment vars is [`getenv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php)

Comment: env() is defined by laravel. I've done a die and dump on the function which creates the connection (vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php line 41) and it returns the right values. To be sure I also copied the second code block from my question into the function, but that also didn't work. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I'm running the project (and the mysql database) inside a virtual machine which runs on ubuntu (as explained in http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead)?

Comment: What is the _full_ 2002 error message? Usually that will point to a socket it's attempting to connect through. The default socket path may differ, or maybe laravel overrides it somewhere?

Comment: Error message + stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/Qdqc26Gu I'm not sure if this is the actual php error message, I think maybe laravel implements its own custom error reporting. EDIT: This is what I get when I run php artisan migrate, by the way. When I access my project via the browser I just get: "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Comment: Look at this: `createConnection('mysql:host=loca...', Array, Array)`  Those `Array,Array` look like PHP array values which were cast to strings (resulting in "Array") in place of the username and password.

Comment: And on top of that, _Can not create a connection because the target computer has actively refused the connection.'_ indicates a TCP connection was attempted instead of a socket, but not the host isn't listening.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed. First off, if you're using a VM, like I am, you can't set your host to localhost, it has to be set to 127.0.0.1. Secondly, the port through which the connection is made needs to be explicitly defined (default for mysql is 33060). So in my case the connection configuration is defined as follows:

```
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'      => '33060',
        'database'  => 'homestead',
        'username'  => 'homestead',
        'password'  => 'secret',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

Lastly, you need to modify the .env file in your project:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very tricky stuff of PDO.

If you set URI as "localhost", PDO will use a local unix socket! Where as a plain IP, PDO will use a TCP connection.